# Apache Flume .tmp files not cleaned up after a force kill + start

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I saw several related questions to this, but didn't quite get what I was looking for. 
I am using Flume 1.8.0 and I'm seeing .tmp files after the Flume agent is killed forcefully. These do not get cleaned up on restart of the flume agent. Is there any way the Flume agent can be configured to do the cleanup, or is this something that I need to handle on my own(outside of Flume)?

This is my flume conf file for my test:

```
agent.sources = seqGenSrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = hdfs1

# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type = seq

# The channel can be defined as follows.
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel

# Each sink's type must be defined
#agent.sinks.loggerSink.type = logger

#Specify the channel the sink should use
#agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.hdfs1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/flume/
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.codeC = bzip2
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.file.Prefix = myfiles-
agent.sinks.hdfs1.channel = memoryChannel

agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.batchSize = 15
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollSize = 1048576
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollInterval = 20
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.writeFormat = Writable
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.timeZone = UTC
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.callTimeout = 60000

agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 0
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 1
agent.sinks.hdfs1.hdfs.retryInterval = 1

# Each channel's type is defined.
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

Start the Flume agent with above conf file.
After it has written a few files to HDFS, kill it using kill -9 .
Check the hdfs dir. There will be a .tmp file.
If we restart the Flume agent, it will resume writing data to HDFS, but it will not close/cleanup the .tmp file.

Answer (score 0):

Flume HDFS sink creates tmp files and once it reaches the limit either size, time or number of events, it rolls the file, means closes the .tmp file and renames it by removing the .tmp extension.
You need to use `kill -15` instead of of `kill -9`, so that flume agent can exit gracefully and it can perform these tasks before stopping the agent.